# jQuery fade in new DIV

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using bitrepository.com great AJAX Form which utilizes jQuery and PHP: http://www.bitrepository.com/a-simple-ajax-contact-form-with-php-validation.html

I'd like the error and validation DIV which appear after click to fade in.

Added the following jQuery code but to no avail (also tried with the click/change functions):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('.notification_error').length > 0) {
        $('.notification_error').fadeTo("slow", 1.0);
    }
});
```

Any help would be great...

Comment: Just FYI, you don't need the if-statement. If your selector doesn't match any elements, no elements will be faded and no error will be thrown, so you could just as well get rid of the if-statement.

Comment: This appears to only run once on load of the document.  You want to execute fadeTo after the user clicked on a submit button, right?  What is the code that executes when the user clicks the button?

Comment: The use of the if statement in this case is unnecessary. JQuery will not thow any exceptions if .notification_error does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your code look exactly like the one you have referenced, you could change your ajax-complete callback to this:

```
$("#note").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){  

   if(msg == 'OK') // Message Sent? Show the 'Thank You' message and hide the form
   {
      result = '<div class="notification_ok">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>';
      $("#fields").hide();
   }
   else
   {
      result = msg;
   }
   /* Hide the element, alter the content, and then fade it in */
   $(this).hide().html(result).fadeIn("slow"); 
});
```

This would fade in both error- and success-messages.

**Update:**

To only fade the element in the first time, you could replace the last line with something like this:

```
if ($(".notification_error, .notification_ok", this).length === 0) {
    $(this).hide().html(result).fadeIn("slow"); 
} else {
    $(this).html(result);
}
```

What we do is that we check if there is a en element with either class `notification_error` or `notification_ok`. If not (the first time) we fade it in, otherwise we just update the content.

Comment: Quick follow up if you have time; since we added .hide(), the DIV gets hidden and fades back in if you click on submit more than once with the error showing. Is there a way to prevent the DIV from hide() if present in HTML?

Comment: @Alex See my updated answer. Haven't tried it, but I think it should work.

Comment: @Alex Whoops sorry, a small typo there. Updated my answer, thanks for the notice!

Comment: @Alex Notice that I had missed a `.` on the `.notification_ok` as well. I have updated it in my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$("#clicked_input_id").click(function(){
    $('.notification_error').fadeTo("slow", 1.0);
});
```